# Run VSCode Portable v1.78 from mapped network drive in Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-10, virtual-machine, portability

I would like to setup VSCode Portable to run from a mapped network drive on a Windows 10 VM with a roaming profile. A previous version 1.64 of VSCode works in this configuration, but not current versions (tried v1.74 and up). When I extract the VSCode v1.78 .Zip file to the H:\ drive, double-clicking the Code.exe doesn't do anything, even when running as Admin.

VSCode is already installed on the Windows 10 VM, but I would like the flexibility of using different versions for debugging and extension compatibility purposes.

Running a VSCode Portable version from a folder on the C:\ drive works, however, it's not persistent when the user logs out and logs back in. For that reason, I would like to extract and run VSCode portable from a mapped network drive like H:\user\PortableApps or shared network drive using the UNC path.

I've tried creating a symlink from the C:\ drive to the VSCode folder on the H:\ drive using the UNC path, but the Code.exe file still will not run. I've also tried searching GitHub and StackOverflow for solutions, but can't seem to find any. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: I was able to get VSCode running on the mapped drive by using the --no-sandbox argument.

When running VSCode from cmd with --verbose, I see there's an error:

"GPU process launch failed: error_code=18"

Using other methods to disable the GPU were unsuccessful, including --disable-GPU and --disable-GPU-sandbox. Using --no-sandbox seems to be the only workaround for now.

Creating a shortcut on the desktop and adding --no-sandbox argument to the end of the target allows it to launch.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/81056

Comment: Update: I was able to get VSCode running by using the --no-sandbox argument.